# How to access to MELPA packages?

Tags: emacs, package, melpa

I've tried to install colour themes that can be found on MELPA, but when I use "M-x install-package", they are not found.

I restart emacs after each modification of the init.el file, and refresh the list of packages before each try.

Here is my init.el file :

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(require 'ggtags)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode 'java-mode 'asm-mode)
              (ggtags-mode 1))))
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g s") 'ggtags-find-other-symbol)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g h") 'ggtags-view-tag-history)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g r") 'ggtags-find-reference)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g f") 'ggtags-find-file)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g c") 'ggtags-create-tags)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g u") 'ggtags-update-tags)

(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "M-,") 'pop-tag-mark)
```

I've installed ggtags and ahundry, but not zenburn or solarized-theme for example.

So can someone please tell me what could be wrong, because I have no idea.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? If you use `M-x package-list-packages`, do you see packages from MELPA in the resulting buffer? Is `zenburn-theme` there?

Comment: Potentially you're just missing a `M-x package-refresh-contents`. That's done automatically if you use the `package-list-packages` UI, but not if you just try to `package-install` something.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on emacs 24.3, and i already tried to refresh the list